# Why isn't it passing test cases i, working alright in vs code when passing individually numbers like 11 etc. (binary to decimal)

Tags: python

```py
from os import *
from sys import *
from collections import *
from math import *

def convert(n, str):
    # Write Your code here.
    j=0
    summ=0
    for i in range(-1,-(n+1),-1):
        if str[i]=='1':
            summ=(summ+(2**j))

        j=j+1
    return summ
    pass
```

> problem link- https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/problems/binary-to-decimal_893273?leftPanelTabValue=SUBMISSION

[image: see the expected and my output and help]

Comment: You know that you're in the wrong "training" environment when the sample code uses built-in class names for variables. *str* in this case

Answer (score -1):

In Python the length of the string is not necessary (as it would be, for example, in C).

Therefore your Python solution is simply:

```
def convert(_, s):
    print(int(s, 2))
```

If you prefer not to use built-in functionality then:

```
def convert(_, s):
    b = 2 ** len(_s := s.lstrip("0"))
    r = 0
    for c in _s:
        b //= 2
        if c == "1":
            r += b
    print(r)
```